# Decide a number $a, b, c$ (expressed by $\lambda$) so that $a\mathbf{u}_1 + b\mathbf{u}_2 + c\mathbf{u}_3 = \mathbf{x}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> See the following vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
>
> $ \mathbf{u}_1=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> -1\\
> 1 \\
> 1
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $,
>   $
> \mathbf{u}_2 = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 2 \\
> 0 \\
> 2
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $,
>   $
> \mathbf{u}_3 = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 \\
> 0 \\
> -1 \\
> 0
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $
>
> and
>
> $ \mathbf{v}_1=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 5 \\
> -3\\
> -4 \\
> -1
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $,
>   $
> \mathbf{v}_2 = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 6 \\
> 4 \\
> 1 \\
> 8
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $,
>   $
> \mathbf{v}_3 = 
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 7 \\
> 2 \\
> -1 \\
> 6
> \end{pmatrix} 
> $
>
> We are told that $\mathcal{B} = (\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_3)$ and $\mathcal{C} = (\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3)$ both are bases for the same subspace $\mathcal{U}$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{\lambda}$ be an unknown number og see the vector $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{v}_1 + \lambda\mathbf{v}_2 - \mathbf{v}_3$.

Decide a number $a, b, c$ (expressed by $\lambda$) so that $a\mathbf{u}_1 + b\mathbf{u}_2 + c\mathbf{u}_3 = \mathbf{x}$

How do I go on about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Find some $\alpha_i$ such that $v_1=\alpha_1 u_1+\alpha_2u_2+\alpha_3u_3$
2. Find some $\beta_i$ such that $v_2=\beta_1 u_1+\beta_2u_2+\beta_3u_3$
3. Find some $\gamma_i$ such that $v_3=\gamma_1 u_1+\gamma_2u_2+\gamma_3u_3$
4. Simplify the expression $$x=v_1+\lambda v_2-v_3=\alpha_1 u_1+\alpha_2u_2+\alpha_3u_3+\lambda(\beta_1 u_1+\beta_2u_2+\beta_3u_3)-(\gamma_1 u_1+\gamma_2u_2+\gamma_3u_3)$$

Comment: Thanks 5xum!

When I reduce it, I get $\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
3\\
-9 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} + a\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
-2\\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix}
3 \\
6\\
0 \\
6
\end{pmatrix} + c\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{pmatrix} $ What do I do from here?

Comment: I managed to solve it following your hint, thank you!